# How can I optimize playing a sentient wolf?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, class

I was invited to a savage themed campaign recently that features shamans, cave monsters, and all that prehistoric goodness.

I'm going to be playing an awakened wolf named Virginia, and have no idea how to build her since she doesn't have hands. The wolf's stats aren't stellar, and I have a level adjustment of 2 to work with as determined by the DM. I'm going for a physical attacker role since wolves suck at everything else. I will be starting at level 5.

Pathfinder material only if you don't mind.

Comment: FWIW, there is precedent for allowing a non-human to use spells with somatic components: http://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/1ihvnp/pathfinder_would_an_awakened_animal_have_somatic/cb4n1jo. The attribute scores might be a bit tricky to get decent though.

Comment: If you're an awakened wolf with an LA of 2, wouldn't that make you ECL 6?  Wolves have base HD of 2, Awaken gives you +2 HD, and then the LA makes 6.  Do you know how the DM determined that LA?  I can't find anything in the wolf's description that would warrant even a +1 LA.  Are you using the normal wolf stats?

Comment: Also, do you know the general power level of the game?  I'm guessing that since it's prehistoric, that weapons are going to be crappier, or at least limited to the ones made of wood and bone.  Is magic similarly limited?  You might be able to be a good battlefield control druid, since you get a +2 to Wisdom.

Comment: How are you doing stats?  Are you doing the normal point buy with your wolf racial stat bonuses (+2 Str, +4 Dex, +4 Con, +2 Wis, -2 Cha), or something different?

Comment: The tech levels and magic levels are lower scale, and I'm using the stats the wolf came with since that's all the DM would allow. As for the level adjustment I have no idea how he did it, the whole process confuses the hell out of me. He said LA 2 so it is.

Comment: I may try and talk him down to LA 1 based on what I'm learning in the comments.

Comment: It sounds like he's taking the +2 HD from the Awaken spell and just using that as the LA...which isn't right.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl The wolf gets really good stat modifiers, has the scent ability, and if it bites gets a free action trip attempt that doesn't provoke an AoO. +2 LA sounds good for that.

Comment: Not with straight 10's.  Asker is using the wolf STATBLOCK, not designing a PC as a wolf.

Comment: Having 4 non-class Hit Die is bad, unless you get some cool abilities that make up for not having actual class features.
Having any LA is very bad. LAs are harsh, because they put you far behind on BAB, and Hit points.
Only worth it if you has some seriously sweet abilities, like damage immunities etc.

I would be trying to talk him out of giving you a LA, possibly by saying you'll take more Animal Hit Die as a compromise. If he is not welling to make the compromise, it is possible that he doesn't actually want you to play a wolf, but didn't want to say no. So consider not playing a wolf.

Comment: Update: He agreed the LA 2 is a bit high and lowered it to LA 1. He mostly needed to be reasoned with. He's not ignoring the HD from awaken though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Hands!? We don't need no stinking hands!***

Play to your strengths! Choose classes that give bonuses to damage, or allows you to better trip people. (This is assuming the DM lets you have the trip ability mentioned [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/wolf), and that you're just taking the monster and playing it as a character. If that's not the case, *ignore everything about trips in this answer*!) More trips give other party members a better chance of doing their damage, which will be greatly appreciated. This is especially true at low levels, where chance plays a much larger role in a party's success.

**Barbarian**

Yes, be a [barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian)! No hands required! I'm assuming you're proficient with your bite attack. The bonuses to rage would be amazing! It's not like you can switch weapons (no hands, just teeth), so getting things which amps up your strength amps up your damage! Since you're a wolf, and naturally have a bite attack, you [add 1-1/2 your strength to attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks). Plus you've already got trip from your wolfi-ness, plus a nice bonus to tracking.

**Ranger**

Nice hit dice. Favored enemies will help you do damage. This class also plays to the strengths of wolves, like tracking, making you more valuable than just a big damage-dealer. Combat Style? Well, if you include the [natural attack style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger#TOC-Combat-Style-Feat-Ex-) as an option, things are looking pretty good. [Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger#TOC-Spells) may be an issue. Additionally, the class works well in wild areas.

**Dip Into Rogue?**

Sneak Attack only requires flanking. You don't need hands to do that! Extra damage dice is nice, but static bonuses to damages results in more consistent damage. Additionally, hit points may be an issue.

Comment: All of these become even better with Alternate Class Features. Examples include: Barbarian: **Savage Barbarian** (bonuses for not wearing armor) and **Mad Dog** (gain a rabid companion = bring you mate). Ranger: **Beastmaster** (gain multiple companions = bring your whole pack!), **Guide** (instead of favored enemy, you focus on any one target), **Skirmisher** (instead of spells, gain a large set of "combat tricks"). Rogue: **Thug** (scary and vicious, no trapfinding), **Scout** (sneak-attack by charging and moving), **Chameleon** (superior hiding in "favored terrain").

Comment: My armor will take a hit but the barbarian is definitely looking like it will be more fun long term.

Answer (score 4):

### Druid

Have a chat with your GM, and have the Natural Spell feat allowed at level 3 instead of level 6.  Then channel the FUREH of NAYTCHAH.  Druids have great spells to buff melee combat, and some of their best spells target animals.  Beast Shape etc aren't limited just to humanoids - you can use it on yourself and pick up abilities you don't have, as well as the stat bonuses.

It's thematic as hell, and being an awakened beast shaman of nature is just a damn cool concept.  Your LA hurts, but you're still playing one of the strongest classes in the game, and the array of options that druid gives you should allow you to contribute in combat no matter where it's occurring.

Plus, you get to be a Wolf, that turns into a Wolf, has a Wolf companion, and summons Wolves.

### Synthesist Summoner

You know that transformers thing, Beast Wars?  This is basically going to be a lot like that.  A Synthesist summoner calls down an EPIC POWERFUL SPIRIT and melds with it, becoming THE BEST OF BOTH WORLDS.

Notably, your melded form can have arms if you so choose - having a humanoid 'spirit form' would let you use spells, and be delightfully weird for a wolf.

Without it, though, you're still really terrifying.  For a start, there are evolutions that improve bite attacks - notably, adding reach, and the ability to 'push' foes away or 'pull' them closer, knock them down, add energy damage to the bite, and all kinds of crazy stuff.  Evolutions that increase strength, increase SIZE, increase natural armour.  That let you FLY.  That give you powerful flaming auras.

It's the 'turn you into a monster' class, and exactly how I would make a 'savage epic magical spirit wolf' in pathfinder.

A version of Natural Spell for summoners could be negotiated with your GM.

### Armoured Tactical Wolf

Weirdly, Fighter could really work as a wolf.  Barding, armoured teeth, and the various feats that spiral around the Trip chain, combat expertise and the like could make you a very tough and hard to deal with wolf.  There's some iconography and trope stuff that works with that too.  We view wolves as being disciplined, in some senses, and being canny fighters.  That works really well with Fighter as a class.  A wolf that embraces civilization and a cool head in savage times is actually a really interesting concept, too.

**'Wolf Flies Through Heavens'**

Wolf Monk.

I'm not going to ruin this with words.

### LA and Stuff

Awakened Wolf has 4 HD, and no listed LA.

Also, those wolf stats are based on the wolf having straight 10's before racial modifiers, like all monster entries.

PCs get to assign stats before racial characteristics.  Apparently you don't add LA to a race if it's CR is lower than it's Racial Hit Dice, which a wolf's isn't (even before you Awaken it).

The wolf has if I am not mistaken:
Str +2
Dex +4
Con +4
Wis +2
Cha -4
It has 2 animal hit dice (d8, medium BAB, good Fort and Ref saves and 2 skillpoints per HD) from race, and 2 further from Awaken.
It has the special abilites like scent, +4 bonus to stealth and perception and +5 bonus to survival when tracking with scent. And it can trip with a bite.

The general advice on the paizo forums seems to be that most GMs would waive the animal HD and allow the wolf player to take PC classes from the get-go, since not having magic item slots/hands is a serious downside, worth the other bonuses.

Comment: Note that monk damage replaces unarmed strike damage; It doesn't add to natural weapon damage. For some reason I've met a lot of people who don't realise this, so I feel compelled to mention it here.

Comment: That's a shame, it would sync really well.

Comment: @Julia - it's worth noting that nothing stops you from using Bite as a secondary natural weapon, with the Multi-Attack feat to only take a -2 penalty for doing so.  You can get an Unarmed Strike/Unarmed Strike/Bite/Trip/Bite attack routine with one level of monk and 2 feats (Improved Trip, Greater Improved Trip).

Answer (score 1):

Wolf monk with the savage combat style feat would be an easy way to use that bite more than once per round.

There's also an actual style feat called wolf style, which helps you trip stuff (but only a little). It's mostly only worthwhile for wolf savage, which lets you curse enemies (as *bestow curse*, unlimited times per day) who you trip and deal damage to. Very thematic.

If you wanna be REAL good at tripping stuff, you could go full dexterity and take fury's fall and weapon finesse. An Amulet of Mighty Fists with the Agile enhancement costs only 4k gold.